How to export a whole dataset from BigQuery to GCS in one go?
I know how to export a table from BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage (via console, SQL or bq). Of course this is time consuming if I have lots of tables to export.
So the question is plain and simple, but I haven't found any solution for this: is there a way to export a whole dataset in one go? I'm looking for some kind of good old mysqldump method. I don't care if the file destination is still GSC, I'm just looking for some kind of automated process so I don't need to export every table individually. Since I need this for the Google Analytics data stored in BQ, the export format would still need to be JSON (because of the nested values).
Thanks.

Well, since I'm working with the Google Analytics data which is located in the tables named events_YYYYMMDD, one answer is obvious (didn't think of it right away though). The steps are:

Query data from all tables using the SQL statement like 'SELECT * FROM events_*'
Save the query results into a new table
Download/export data from the new table to Google Cloud Storage as a JSON file (or other format if you preffer)
Download the file from the GCS to your computer

The steps above work because I'm dealing with the tables that use the similar name and the same schema. Still, if there's a better/quicker solution or if there's more automated way to do this, please let me know.
Dealing with tables with different schemas would still need another approach. So if someone has the answer to the original question, please let me know.

You could use the BigQuery EXPORT DATA statement to skip step 2. But other than that, I don't think there is really anything more convenient. What I am usually doing in this case is writing a small bash script that runs the query, exports the data to GCS and then downloads the data via gcloud. And if the tables have different structures you could write a SQL script that iterates over the INFORMATION_SCHEMA data for that dataset and use EXECUTE IMMIDIATE to export the data.

Thanks. Will check do some research about everything you wrote. It seems logical.
